# MatterMost retrieve posts since timestamp

Tags: curl, mattermost

Using MM `5.26.1`, I'm performing the following commands which work:

```sh
$ curl -i -d '{"login_id":"mihai","password":"bCsTx6GZZAAAAAA"}' http://localhost:8065/api/v4/users/login

# now have a token which I can use for subsequent queries

$ curl -i -H 'Authorization: Bearer 4jymwea6btbqmre61wx6XXXXXX'  http://localhost:8065/api/v4/channels
...
{
    "id": "y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo",
    "create_at": 1603220311102,
    "update_at": 1603220311102,
    "delete_at": 0,
    "team_id": "iax6hqhw7idkidbs5rz4mi4skr",
    "type": "O",
    "display_name": "Town Square",
    "name": "town-square",
    "header": "",
    "purpose": "",
    "last_post_at": 1603220326473,
    "total_msg_count": 1,
    "extra_update_at": 0,
    "creator_id": "",
    "scheme_id": null,
    "props": null,
    "group_constrained": null,
    "team_display_name": "foo",
    "team_name": "foo",
    "team_update_at": 1603220311101
  }
```

Beautiful. Now I would like to retrieve the posts for `town-square`:

```sh
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer 4jymwea6btbqmre61wx6XXXXXX'  http://localhost:8065/api/v4/channels/y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo/posts             mihai@mihai-pc 11/03/21 20:29:42
{"order":["zbiymegh7ifabdforzpykd7zye","sm65ahhbbpr5ims7aixfinpryc","m8dsdxbcr3d7mkarcnyni7d3dw","6ab58mn8wt8kmejcu54py5kijo"],"posts":{"6ab58mn8wt8kmejcu54py5kijo":{"id":"6ab58mn8wt8kmejcu54py5kijo","create_at":1603220311183,"update_at":1603220311183,"edit_at":0,"delete_at":0,"is_pinned":false,"user_id":"g1qsr6ebubghudqfzwryegi48c","channel_id":"y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo","root_id":"","parent_id":"","original_id":"","message":"mihaigalos joined the team.","type":"system_join_team","props":{"username":"mihaigalos"},"hashtags":"","pending_post_id":"","reply_count":0,"metadata":{}},"m8dsdxbcr3d7mkarcnyni7d3dw":{"id":"m8dsdxbcr3d7mkarcnyni7d3dw","create_at":1603220326473,"update_at":1603220326473,"edit_at":0,"delete_at":0,"is_pinned":false,"user_id":"g1qsr6ebubghudqfzwryegi48c","channel_id":"y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo","root_id":"","parent_id":"","original_id":"","message":"hello everyone!","type":"","props":{"disable_group_highlight":true},"hashtags":"","pending_post_id":"","reply_count":0,"metadata":{}},"sm65ahhbbpr5ims7aixfinpryc":{"id":"sm65ahhbbpr5ims7aixfinpryc","create_at":1615480126769,"update_at":1615480126769,"edit_at":0,"delete_at":0,"is_pinned":false,"user_id":"g1qsr6ebubghudqfzwryegi48c","channel_id":"y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo","root_id":"","parent_id":"","original_id":"","message":"This is a test.","type":"","props":{"disable_group_highlight":true},"hashtags":"","pending_post_id":"","reply_count":0,"metadata":{}},"zbiymegh7ifabdforzpykd7zye":{"id":"zbiymegh7ifabdforzpykd7zye","create_at":1615480129626,"update_at":1615480129626,"edit_at":0,"delete_at":0,"is_pinned":false,"user_id":"g1qsr6ebubghudqfzwryegi48c","channel_id":"y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo","root_id":"","parent_id":"","original_id":"","message":"And another one.","type":"","props":{"disable_group_highlight":true},"hashtags":"","pending_post_id":"","reply_count":0,"metadata":{}}},"next_post_id":"","prev_post_id":""}
```

Awesome.
However, when I try to query after a specific Unix timestamp in milliseconds, it doesn't work. Why?

```sh
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer 4jymwea6btbqmre61wx6XXXXXX' -d '{"since":1603200000000}'  http://localhost:8065/api/v4/channels/y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo/posts 
{"id":"api.context.404.app_error","message":"Sorry, we could not find the page.","detailed_error":"There doesn't appear to be an api call for the url='/api/v4/channels/y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo/posts'.  Typo? are you missing a team_id or user_id as part of the url?","status_code":404}
```

My team is called `foo`, so I tried with the URL `http://localhost:8065/api/v4/foo/channels/y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo/posts`, still no luck..

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is interested, I managed to get it working with this:

```sh
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer 4jymwea6btbqmre61wx6XXXXXX' http://localhost:8065/api/v4/channels/y4srrjqzoj8aunnnakb8px79eo/posts\?since\=1603220326473
```